# How do you set object access from shared publicly to only being able to access the file momentarily?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I've been playing around in google cloud storage. I've been able to upload files without any signature mismatch errors by doing the following.

1. set cors using gsutils from a json file.
2. get signed urls with an additional `'x-goog-acl': 'project-private'` key value (or at least I think I have)
3. and PUT my object to storage with an additional body object `'x-goog-acl': 'project-private'`

It doesn't seem to do anything. When I look in the console my image file is still shared publicly.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is that the user that is authenticated in my web app is the only person that can access that file. How can I do that I thought it was ACL permissions but I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: Have you thought of giving a specific [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#roles) role ([here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) you can find different roles) for that user(ie the authenticated user from your app) ?.

Comment: @Digil I did try to do that but maybe I have to read it again doing something wrong. I'm having trouble understanding how IAM role and ACL's are implemented.

Comment: You can also go through [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions) help center article on how to use the IAM permission for more details. Additionally, you can check this various ['Controlling Access'](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/how-to#controlling-access) scenarios that can be implemented on the bucket and its objects as well.